# Rookie: How to properly start Ethereum console?

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new to Ethereum. In order to start Ethereum I am using the following command:

> geth start

Is this correct? As it goes into an endless loop of listing information. I have waited for an hour and it still keeps listing info with no console?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search on google lead to this:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

You need to search your own answers before asking a question, because it's usually already been asked ;)

Guide to make a custom blockchain with geth :

https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I should have stated in my original question that after having read the documentation on [https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) I am unable to find the correct parameter combination to turn on Etherium for a private block chain instance (learning).

Comment: You need to use the init command to load a genesis

Comment: I edited my answer with a link that will be usefull to you!  if it helped! Please mark my post as answer :)